# Is Lorna Bucket actually Melody Pond AKA River Song?

Tags: doctor-who, river-song

Having seen the name Melody Pond become River Song, I wondered about Lorna Bucket.

She seemed such a strange & interesting character to put in but then have die.
Lorna means abandoned. Bucket, a round container with water in it could also be a pond....yes it’s a stretch. But Melody Pond being River Song was a stretch too, in a good way.

So, born Melody Pond & taken to brainwash so would kill Doctor as a child.
Then we hear nothing of what happened from being a child to being Melody her best friend = River Song.
Could she have been “‘abandoned’ ‘water in round container’”?

Yes I know 2 problems:

1. ....”the only Water in the forest is a river”. But that’s only where she met Doctor 11 & grew up, nothing to say she was born & named on there.
2. a pond doesn’t mean it’s a ROUND body of water in a container (earth) whereas a bucket is usually round.

Comment: Given that she died, it seems unlikely.

Comment: Yes she died, as did the Doctor’s  Daughter, & as some previous Doctors have before.......sometimes regeneration doesn’t happen immediately.

Comment: This seems like such an incredible reach. Yes, you can put water in a bucket, but you can also put a load of things that *aren't* water in a bucket.

Comment: Certainly a step down, namewise.

Comment: Problem number three: ["Lorna" means "fox"](https://www.babynames.com/name/Lorna), not anything musical.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: I wouldn't trust babynames.com to have correct etymologies. [Behind the name](https://www.behindthename.com/name/lorna) says it's a literary name invented in 1869. But you're right, it has nothing to do with "forlorn" or anything musical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am wondering if you have seen the whole of the rest of the season. If not, **stop reading** and carry on watching as below are spoilers that show exactly why this cannot be the case.

In a word, no, she isn’t - there is no way she could be, as we know her timeline.

The timeline of River Song is as follows.

1. River is born – *A Good Man Goes to War* (2011). Baby River is taken by Madame Kovarian to fulfill her destiny and taken back in time to 1969
2. Wears a space suit and gets shot – *The Impossible Astronaut* (2011) she is shot by Amy her eventual mother. 6 months later
3. Regenerates in New York – *Day of the Moon* (2011). This is her first ever regeneration. This is important, as remember Timelords (who are not the Doctor) have just 12 regenerations. She regenerates as Mel. Mel states in *Let's Kill Hitler* when she regenerates into River Song, "Last time I did this I ended up as a toddler, in New York". So we know that Mel is this regeneration.
4. *Let's Kill Hitler* (2011) Mel goes back in time with the Doctor, Rory, and Amy, and tries to kill Hitler and then the Doctor. She regenerates into River Song (regeneration number 2) and the Doctor sacrifices himself to save her. She then gives up her remaining 10 regenerations to save his life.

From then until she “dies” in the library she is just River Song no more regenerations no more changes.

This is an official timeline as defined by the writers of the series, so as much as you may want it to be different, there is no way that Lorna Bucket is River Song.

Comment: “Lorna is of Old English origin. It is derived from the element lorn meaning 'lost, forsaken'.“

Comment: I didn’t think we saw River generate into Mel, have I actually missed an episode?

Comment: Re bucket, yes can’t disagree with that. Basically this was just a thought in my head which I thought I’d throw out there to see what others thought. So I appreciate all your comments on it 

Comment: When Mel regenerates into river she says “last time I did this I ended up a toddler, in New York” that ties in with what you see at the end of day of the moon.

Comment: @Martha Edit comments also need to abide by the CoC, you don't need to be so snarky, remember English isn't everyone's first language.

Comment: @Missymouse2: that's folk/false etymology. Lorna is a literary name invented in 1869, possibly based on a Scottish placename. Nothing to do with "lorn".